# Black Alpha in Textures on Android When Using OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

There are numerous answers to similar questions but I don't think they apply to me. When I use OpenGL ES 1, the alpha is blended properly. On most phones, the alpha is blended properly. On some phones, I get pure opaque black where there should be no pixels drawn. I'm loading textures with premultiplied alpha. I tried using the Java loaders and also using libpng (I'm using a library, Allegro, where this is easy) with no change. For blending Allegro uses:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I think this is correct for premultiplied alpha as it works on most Androids, all PCs, Macs etc. I'm thinking there might be some state I'm not initializing that only matters on certain phones or where the defaults are different, but I'm not sure.

I've tried loading the textures as 32 bit with alpha and 16 bit with alpha with no difference in display.

This is how I set up the texture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, pix_size);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
    w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
```

This is library code so when I used 16 bit textures the last line changes to:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA4,
    w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, buf);
```

Comment: Posting the code for how you set up the texture might help narrow down the problem. Your blend function looks correct though.

Comment: I've edited and added my texture setup code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Allegro (the library my game uses) uses glBlendFuncSeparate when using OpenGL ES 2.0 -- which SHOULD work, but some phones don't support it apparently. Using glBlendFunc fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess.

You should use **GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT** flag in **glClear** function if you want to blending:

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)